# Showing menu on mousemove – stay on mouseover

Tags: menu, hover, hide, show, mousemove

I have a menu that only shows on mousemove. I want it to stay displayed when the mouse is hovering the menu area.

I have the following code for now, not sure how to change it to fit my needs.

```
var timer;
$("html").on('mousemove', function() {
$('nav').addClass('show');
try {
    clearTimeout(timer);
} catch (e) {}
timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $('nav').removeClass('show');
}, 2000);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the nicest way, but got the result by using this if statement:

```
var timer;
$("html").on('mousemove', function() {
$('nav').addClass('show');
try {
    clearTimeout(timer);
} catch (e) {}

if ($('nav:hover').length != 0) {
}else
timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $('nav').removeClass('show');
}, 2000);
});
```